# Setup SNI in directadmin

Tags: ssl, pki, sni

I got some issues with setting up SNI in directadmin. 
I've added enable_ssl_sni=1 to my directadmin.conf and I still get this error:

```
Cannot Execute Your Request

Details

You can only add a certificate if you own the ip you are using

Info for Admins: Assigning an owned IP
```

But the whole idea behind that SNI is that you don't need to assign an owned IP?

So my question is, what to do to make SNI work in Directadmin. That enable_ssl_sni=1 should disable the check but it isn't doing that. And at http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=284 I don't see the option enable_ssl_sni at all?

Comment: DirectAdmin internal questions are better fit for the [DirectAdmin forums](http://forum.directadmin.com/), where excellent support is given by both the creators and experienced users. It's unlikely that you'll get an equally good answer here. Also, since it's not related to coding it's offtopic on SO anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add enable_ssl_sni=1 to /usr/local/directadmin/conf/directadmin.conf

Danijel,

Comment: I already solved the issue thanks to DA support, the issue was that I forgot to add a newline after it... :)

Comment: If it would be possible, I would have upvoted this comment. Darn, you saved me a lot of time: I also pasted the enable_ssl_sni=1 but left out the newline, duh!